# Change a letter after clicking on a button

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to change the first letter of my `TextView` after clicking on a button in Eclipse Android. I already can change the whole `TextView`, but I only want to change the first letter. How does it work?

**XML:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnKlick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="209dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Eclipse"
        android:textSize="70sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA:**

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public Button btn;
    public TextView tw;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnKlick);
        tw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        {}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `onClick` function:

```
String text = tw.getText().toString();
String newText = "C" + text.substring(1);
//                ^-- your new letter
tw.setText(newText)
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to change another letter, its quite easy!

```
String text = tw.getText().toString();
int n = 3; // <-- nth letter
String newText = text.substring(0, n) + "C" + text.substring(n + 1);
//                                       ^-- your new letter
tw.setText(newText)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how to colour the C?

Comment: @user3341325 Directly it is impossible, But you can get a workaround to achieve your purpose, In this workaround you should put 3 `TextView`s together in a line, then you can change the color on the middle one. However if you found my answer helpful please accept it by clicking on the tick icon

Answer (score 5):

Something like this may work.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // get the current string
    String toChange = tw.getText().toString();

    // get the part of the string you want to keep [everything after the first letter]
    String toKeep = toChange.subString(1, toChange.length);

    // put the letter you want before the part of the string you wanted to keep.
    toChange = "PUT_YOUR_NEW_LETTER_HERE".concat(toKeep);

    // finally set the new string in your TextView
    tw.setText(toChange);
}
```

If you explain more clearly what you want to achieve I could help you better.

As you've asked on how to replace a character amid a String I recommend you to have a look at @Rafik991 's answer. You simply can use something like the following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int index = 0; // the index at which you want to replace a char.
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(tw.getText);
    stringBuilder.replace(index, index + 1, "YOUR_NEW_CHAR_AS_A_STRING");
    tw.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

To understand the methods of `StringBuilder` better have a look at the [official documentation,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Just looked at the [StringBuilder documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Wouldn't it be even better to use replace(0, 1, "NEW_CHAR") for your answer? :)

Comment: Yes ;) it is better but I was hurrying up with writing this post. I will change it. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of onChange method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        String cos = tw.getText();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(cos);

        stringBuilder.replace(0, 1, 'c'); // c is your new character
   //or stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
   //   stringBuilder.setCharAt(0,'c');

        tw.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that solution. That's pretty nice actually.

Comment: I did not ask the question and thus can't accept your answer but I voted it up.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String text = tw.getText().toString();  
String substring = text.substring(1, text.length());
tw.setText(substring);
```

Comment: This only deletes the first letter?!